# django filter out latest records

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

These are models defined like:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

    def latest_bar(self):
        try:
            return self.bar_set.latest()
        except Bar.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_date',) 
        get_latest_by = 'created_date'
```

Then the records are created as:

```
f1 = Foo.objects.create(name="F1")
f1.save()

f2 = Foo.objects.create(name="F2")
f2.save()

f3 = Foo.objects.create(name="F3")
f3.save()

b1 = Bar.objects.create(name='B1', foo=f1)
b1.save()

b2 = Bar.objects.create(name='B2', foo=f1)
b2.save()

b3 = Bar.objects.create(name='B3', foo=f1)
b3.save()

b4 = Bar.objects.create(name='B4', foo=f2)
b4.save()

b5 = Bar.objects.create(name='B5', foo=f2)
b5.save()

b6 = Bar.objects.create(name='B6', foo=f3)
b6.save()

b7 = Bar.objects.create(name='B7', foo=f3)
b7.save()
```

What I want to get is latest 'Bar's  for all the 'Foo's, which is

```
[f1.latest_bar(), f2.latest_bar(), f3.latest_bar()]

=> [<Bar: B3>, <Bar: B5>, <Bar: B7>]
```

since there could be large number of Foo, if I do that by:

```
bars = []
for f in Foo.objects.all():
    b = f.latest_bar()
    if b:
        bars.append(b)
```

that may cost a lot of time, is it possible to achieve that by using queryset filter?

Comment: we need more information. Post your `models.py` so we know how to construct the queries. For 1. you'll do something like `model.objects.values('name')`. Check out the django docs on queries [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question with updated example and also requirement changed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a list of objects then this should work:

```
MyModel.objects.values('name').annotate(max_created_date=Max('created_date'))
```

Comment: how can I get the list of the objects rather than the list of the values. which means I want to see:
    <mymodel #5> foo
    <mymodel #6> xyz
    <mymodel #8> bar

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've updated my question with a more exactly matching requirement.